# A newbie question. What are **.config.js and **.vue.js files? How is it different from normal .js file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My question sounds very basic but I do not know the answer and I could not found them by searching.

I have seen files like `vue.config.js` created by vue-cli. I have also seen files like `Content.vue.js`.

I thought that after period `.`, it is the file extension. How can these two have two period?
What is the difference between `.config.js` and `.vue.js` files to normal `.js files`? When to use them?

Thank you!

Comment: "Content.vue.js" - where did you see this? vue.config.js can be seen in all Vue CLI projects, but not this one.

Comment: What I mean is ``****.vue.js``. ``Content.vue.js`` is just an example of file. What is ``.vue.js`` file? Difference between normal ``.js`` file?

Comment: I don't know what's .vue.js file, because such files aren't common. You probably meant .vue files, but then the question was asked the wrong way, and you put different things together that shouldn't be compared. .config.js is valid JS with special purpose. .vue file is not .js, and is not valid JavaScript, although it contains valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it helps to free your mind of any kind of strict view of file extensions. File extensions don't *really* exist, they are just an optional hint put there by whoever created the file as to what the content or the format might be. You could have a file with no extension, or a file that is "only" an extension (often called dotfiles and used for configuration), like `.gitignore` or `.bashrc`.

So, in this case, the creator of `vue.config.js` decided that the best hint for the content is the "extension" `.config.js`. It can have two periods because there aren't really any strict rules saying that it can't.